# Where to write SQL Statements or queries in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql

I know, asking this is a funny thing. But i am new to SQL Server and i don't know where to write SQL Queries? I learned whole SQL Tutorial but i don't know where to write these queries. I have SQL Server 2008 installed . I don't find any textarea to write queries in SQL Server 2008

Thanks in advance....

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio, do you have an Express version? If so from memory you have to get it as a seperate download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have  SQL Server Management Studio installed? Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) that should help you.
Here are a few more links:

1. [SQL Server Management Studio for SQL 2008 express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)
2. [SQL Server Management Studio for SQL 2012 express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Comment: thanks..i understood that sql server management studio is required to write queries to access database.

Comment: @user1648559 how about start accepting answers? This motivates other users to answer you questions, you can upvote (when some answer is helpful), you can downvote (when something is wrong and misleading) and you can accept answers (when you've found the best one)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read a [SQL Server 2008 Tutorial](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/).  It will help you get rolling.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, from personal experience, install it as *a new instance*. It will save you some headaches! If you have trouble installing it, and you can't finish it correctly, there may be a collition with a previous SQL installation. You can solve that problem by uninstalling in *Control Panel* previous SQL stuff. Good luck!